Issue with Generics in build_with_provider Method Implementation for EthereumCheckpointStorageBuilder
I'm trying to implement the method build_with_provider for a generic struct EthereumCheckpointStorageBuilder. Both the struct and the method use the same generic constraint: M: Middleware + 'static.
I want to declare the generic parameter M once and use it in both the struct and the method. However, I'm encountering the following error:
method `build_with_provider` has 0 type parameters but its trait declaration has 1 type parameter

I attempted to add a separate generic parameter P to build_with_provider, but it feels redundant and introduces issues with From. Here's what I tried:
async fn build_with_provider<P>(
    ...
) -> Self::Output 
where
    P: Middleware + 'static,
    M: From<P>,


Is there a cleaner way to declare the generic parameter without repeating it, and how can I resolve the error?
Struct and Trait Definitions
Below is the relevant code:
// Struct definition
pub struct EthereumCheckpointStorageBuilder<M> {
    _phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<M>,
}

// Trait Implementation
#[async_trait]
impl<M> BuildableWithProvider for EthereumCheckpointStorageBuilder<M>
where
    M: Middleware + 'static,
{
    type Output = EthereumCheckpointStorage<M>;
    const NEEDS_SIGNER: bool = true;

    async fn build_with_provider(
        &self,
        provider: M,
        conn: &ConnectionConf,
        locator: &ContractLocator,
    ) -> Self::Output {
        EthereumCheckpointStorage::new(Arc::new(provider), conn, locator)
    }
}

// Trait Definition
#[async_trait]
pub trait BuildableWithProvider {
    async fn build_with_provider<M>(
        &self,
        provider: M,
        conn: &ConnectionConf,
        locator: &ContractLocator,
    ) -> Self::Output
    where
        M: Middleware + 'static;
}


Are you able to change the trait definition? With the trait defined as is you can't make the generic parameters equal.

@cafce25 Tweaking the trait definition isn't the go-to solution here unless it's unavoidable

Well as I said, with this definition you can't reuse the generic.
